# Is it possible and what would be the best approach to completely secure a form in a react app without backend

Tags: reactjs, forms, security, client-server

I got that friend who want me to build a website for him.
There will be no database, no need of Auth or anything like that, only text, images, embed streams and other stuff but nothing that needs a backend except that one form.

Well the problem is that he doesn't want to change his hosting plan that he already has and it's a really basic one that only support php.

I could use php but I really want to avoid it if possible..
I recently learned react and I would like to build the website as a react app, but I don't know if it's possible to fully secure the form since I can't use server side with nodeJS to manage that.

If it's possible, what would be the best approach to do so?
Its just a contact form so there will never be any interaction with a database or any hypothetical backend code, so just using all basic stuff like data binding etc and maybe use a captcha would be enough? I'm pretty sure that's risky anyway so I want to know if there is a way to do it or if I need to use php anyway to handle the form in the server side.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your friend is receiving less than 500 emails per day, he can use EmailJS (a service that solves this sort of problem with an accompanying NPM package) for free. See [this walkthrough](https://www.webtips.dev/react-contact-form-without-backend) on how to implement it.

And with the captcha verification, you can do it on the frontend as well using reaptcha. See [this walkthrough](https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-recaptcha-react-application/#using-reaptcha-router) and skip to the part titled "Using the reaptcha wrapper".

To combine the two to fit your needs, put the <Reaptcha .../> component from walkthrough 2 into your form from walkthrough 1, and then check that the user completed the reaptcha by checking the captchaToken state before doing emailjs.send().

Comment: Thanks mate I'm gonna look into this!